# MS Access Consolidating two text boxes (used for searching) into one

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form that has two text boxes (CardSwipe and EmployeeSearch) and a list box (EmployeeList) .

The EmployeeList displays employee first and last names as well as their ID number.

EmployeeSearch is a search as you type field and allows for searching EmployeeList by any of the fields.  It calls a function "fLiveSearch" in order to achieve this and relies on refreshing the form per change in the field.

CardSwipe allows you to swipe an ID card with the employee ID encoded in it and navigate directly to the record in EmployeeList.

The card that's swiped has the employee ID embedded within a long strand of numbers.  When the card is swiped it's read as if the user has just typed all of the information in really fast. All of these strands on the cards start with the number 6.... There are no ID numbers (or names for that matter) that start with this number.

I would like to consolidate EmployeeSearch and CardSwipe into one text box... But am unsure how to do it.

Below is the code associated with the functions above:

**EmployeeSearch:**

```
Private Sub EmployeeSearch_Change()
'CODE THAT HANDLES WHAT HAPPENS WHEN THE USER TYPES IN THE SEARCH BOX

Dim strFullList As String
Dim strFilteredList As String


If blnSpace = False Then
    Me.Refresh  'refresh to make sure the text box changes are actually available to use

    'specify the default/full rowsource for the control
    strFullList = "SELECT EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID AS [Emp ID], EM_Employees_T.Emp_First AS [First], EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last AS [Last], EM_Employees_T.Email, EM_Employees_T.Full_Time AS [Full Time], EM_Employees_T.Visa_Exp, EM_Employees_T.Visa_ID, EM_Employees_T.Added, EM_Employees_T.Added_by, EM_Employees_T.Modified, EM_Employees_T.Modified_by " & vbCrLf & _
                  "FROM EM_Employees_T " & vbCrLf & _
                  "WHERE (((EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>0 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>2 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>20)) " & vbCrLf & _
                  "ORDER BY EM_Employees_T.Emp_First, EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last;"

    'specify the way you want the rowsource to be filtered based on the user's entry
    strFilteredList = "SELECT EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID AS [Emp ID], EM_Employees_T.Emp_First AS [First], EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last AS [Last], EM_Employees_T.Email, EM_Employees_T.Full_Time AS [Full Time], EM_Employees_T.Visa_Exp, EM_Employees_T.Visa_ID, EM_Employees_T.Added, EM_Employees_T.Added_by, EM_Employees_T.Modified, EM_Employees_T.Modified_by " & vbCrLf & _
                      "FROM EM_Employees_T " & vbCrLf & _
                      "WHERE (((EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>0 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>2 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>20) AND ((EM_Employees_T.Emp_First) Like ""*" & Me.EmployeeSearch & "*"")) OR (((EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>0 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>2 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>20) AND ((EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last) Like ""*" & Me.EmployeeSearch & "*"")) " & vbCrLf & _
                      "ORDER BY EM_Employees_T.Emp_First, EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last;"

    'run the search
    fLiveSearch Me.EmployeeSearch, Me.EmployeeList, strFullList, strFilteredList    ', Me.txtCount
    End If
End Sub
```

**CardSwipe:**

```
Private Sub CardSwipe_AfterUpdate()

Me.EmployeeList.Value = Mid(Me.CardSwipe, 7, 10)
Me.CardSwipe = ""

End Sub
```

**fLiveSearch:**

```
Function fLiveSearch(ctlSearchBox As TextBox, ctlFilter As Control, _
                     strFullSQL As String, strFilteredSQL As String, Optional ctlCountLabel As Control)
'==================================================================================
'  THIS FUNCTION ALLOWS YOU TO FILTER A COMBO BOX OR LIST BOX AS THE USER TYPES
'  ALL YOU NEED TO DO IS PASS IN THE CONTROL REFERENCE TO THE SEARCH BOX ON YOUR
'  FORM, THE LISTBOX/COMBO BOX YOU WANT TO FILTER, AND WHAT THE FULL AND FILTERED
'  SQL (ROWSOURCE) SHOULD BE.
'
'  ctlSearchBox       THE TEXTBOX THE USER TYPES IN TO SEARCH
'
'  ctlFilter          THE LISTBOX OR COMBOBOX ON THE FORM YOU WANT TO FILTER
'
'  strFullSQL         THE FULL ROWSOURCE YOU WANT TO DISPLAY AS A DEFAULT IF NO
'                     RESULTS ARE RETURNED
'
'  strFilteredSQL     THE FILTERED ROWSOURCE FOR THE LISTBOX/COMBOBOX; FOR EXAMPLE
'                     YOU WOULD WANT TO USE '...like ""*" & me.txtsearch.value & "*"""
'                     TO FILTER THE RESULTS BASED ON THE USER'S SEARCH INPUT
'
' ctlCountLabel       (OPTIONAL) THE LABEL ON YOUR FORM WHERE YOU WANT TO DISPLAY THE
'                     COUNT OF ROWS DISPLAYED IN THE LISTBOX/COMBOBOX AS THEY SEARCH
'=====================================================================================

'ADVANCED PARAMETERS - Change these constants to change the behaviour of the search
    Const iSensitivity = 1    'Set to the number of characters the user must enter before the search starts
    Const blnEmptyOnNoMatch = True    'Set to true if you want nothing to appear if nothing matches their search


10  On Error GoTo err_handle

    'restore the cursor to where they left off
20  ctlSearchBox.SetFocus
30  ctlSearchBox.SelStart = Len(ctlSearchBox.Value) + 1

40  If ctlSearchBox.Value <> "" Then
        'Only fire if they've input more than two characters (otherwise it's wasteful)
50      If Len(ctlSearchBox.Value) > iSensitivity Then
60          ctlFilter.RowSource = strFilteredSQL
70          If ctlFilter.ListCount > 0 Then
80              ctlSearchBox.SetFocus
90              ctlSearchBox.SelStart = Len(ctlSearchBox.Value) + 1
100         Else
110             If blnEmptyOnNoMatch = True Then
120                 ctlFilter.RowSource = ""
130             Else
140                 ctlFilter.RowSource = strFullSQL
150             End If
160         End If
170     Else
180         ctlFilter.RowSource = strFullSQL
190     End If

200 Else
210     ctlFilter.RowSource = strFullSQL
220 End If

    'if there is a count label, then update it
230 If IsMissing(ctlCountLabel) = False Then
240     ctlCountLabel.Caption = "Displaying " & Format(ctlFilter.ListCount - 1, "#,##0") & " records"
250 End If

260 Exit Function
err_handle:
270 Select Case Err.Number
    Case 91    'no ctlCountLabel
        'exit
280 Case 94    'null string
        'exit
290 Case Else
300     MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred: " & vbCrLf & Err.Description & _
               vbCrLf & "Error " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Line: " & Erl
310 End Select


End Function
```

Thanks in advance for your input and help.

[edit: fixed formatting]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create consolidated text box
2. Detect if value in consolidated text box is employee ID

   2.1. if **yes** then launch `Cardswipe_AfterUpdate()` referring to consolidated text box value

   2.2. if **no** then launch `EmployeeSearch_Change()` referring to consolidated text box value

Note: expressions like `"*" & Me.EmployeeSearch & "*"` are open doors for [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Try closing that door.

Comment: Miroxlav, thanks for your input, sorry for the delayed response (been working out the code).  It was just what I needed to point me in the right direction (I'll post my updated code below).  On the topic of SQL injection attacks, I'm not sure how I would change my SQL statement to be more secure... changing it is a little beyond me right now... Do you have any suggestions or resources I could use?  I've looked at a few web pages... but none seem to address this particular usage of the wild card (that I can comprehend).

Answer (score 0):

My updated working code:

```
Private Sub EmployeeSearch_AfterUpdate()

    Dim Textcheck As String

    Textcheck = Nz(Left(Me.EmployeeSearch.Text, 1), "")

    Select Case Textcheck

    Case 6

        If Len(Me.EmployeeSearch.Text) >= 17 Then

            Me.EmployeeList.Value = Mid(Me.EmployeeSearch.Text, 7, 10)

            Me.EmployeeSearch.Value = ""

            Me.EmployeeSearch.ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If

    End Select

End Sub



Private Sub EmployeeSearch_Change()
'CODE THAT HANDLES WHAT HAPPENS WHEN THE USER TYPES IN THE SEARCH BOX
    Dim strFullList As String
    Dim strFilteredList As String

    If (Me.EmployeeSearch Is Me.ActiveControl) Then

        If Nz(Left(Me.EmployeeSearch.Text, 1), "") = 6 Then
            Me.EmployeeSearch.ForeColor = RGB(255, 255, 153)

            If Len(Me.EmployeeSearch.Text) >= 18 Then

                SendKeys "{TAB}", False

            End If

        Else



          If blnSpace = False Then
              Me.Refresh  'refresh to make sure the text box changes are actually available to use

                'specify the default/full rowsource for the control
      strFullList = "SELECT EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID AS [Emp ID], EM_Employees_T.Emp_First AS [First], EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last AS [Last], EM_Employees_T.Email, EM_Employees_T.Full_Time AS [Full Time], EM_Employees_T.Visa_Exp, EM_Employees_T.Visa_ID, EM_Employees_T.Added, EM_Employees_T.Added_by, EM_Employees_T.Modified, EM_Employees_T.Modified_by " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM EM_Employees_T " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>0 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>2 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>20)) " & vbCrLf & _
"ORDER BY EM_Employees_T.Emp_First, EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last;"

        'specify the way you want the rowsource to be filtered based on the user's entry
      strFilteredList = "SELECT EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID AS [Emp ID], EM_Employees_T.Emp_First AS [First], EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last AS [Last], EM_Employees_T.Email, EM_Employees_T.Full_Time AS [Full Time], EM_Employees_T.Visa_Exp, EM_Employees_T.Visa_ID, EM_Employees_T.Added, EM_Employees_T.Added_by, EM_Employees_T.Modified, EM_Employees_T.Modified_by " & vbCrLf & _
"FROM EM_Employees_T " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (((EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>0 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>2 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>20) AND ((EM_Employees_T.Emp_First) Like ""*" & Me.EmployeeSearch & "*"")) OR (((EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>0 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>2 And (EM_Employees_T.Emp_ID)<>20) AND ((EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last) Like ""*" & Me.EmployeeSearch & "*"")) " & vbCrLf & _
"ORDER BY EM_Employees_T.Emp_First, EM_Employees_T.Emp_Last;"

                'run the search
              fLiveSearch Me.EmployeeSearch, Me.EmployeeList, strFullList, strFilteredList    ', Me.txtCount
          End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```